# function constructor with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Why does `d.age()` in this example not work?

```
function Dog(input) {
    this.name = input;
    this.color = function(){
        return 'black';
    }
    this.age = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            return '10';
        }, 500);
    }    
}  

window.d = new Dog('Blacky');
```

Comment: It does work. But `return`ing inside of `setTimeout` does nothing, because it's asynchronous. The return value of `setTimeout` is an "id". You'll need to pass a callback to `this.age` to execute when the timeout has been reached, so you can access that `"10"` (or whatever value): http://jsfiddle.net/CaeEL/

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You have not even shown a call to the function you say isn't working.

Comment: As a side note - don't use the string `'10'` where you want the number `10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has no "wait". You either return immediately, or execute a callback later:

```
function Dog(input) {
    this.name = input;
    this.color = function() {
        return 'black';
    }

    // returning a value works just fine:
    this.ageImmediate = function() {
        return 10;
    }
    // but if we want to return after a delay, we have to use a callback
    this.ageDelayed = function(cb) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            cb(10);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

```
var d = new Dog('Blacky');

console.log("returned", d.ageImmediate());
d.ageDelayed(function(age) {
    console.log("from callback", age);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works but not as you expect, you must use a callback system :

```
function Dog(input) {
    this.name = input;
    this.color = function(){
        return 'black';
    }
    this.age = function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback('10');
        }, 500);
    }    
}  

window.d = new Dog('Blacky');
d.age(function(age){
// do some stuff with age
});
```

Also have a look at jquery.deffered http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Answer (score 0):

When you call age() the timeout is started and the function returns undefined, because you do not return anything in your function. Then after 500 ms the timeout triggers and that function returns 10.

So I do not know what you want this function to do.